# How is the input capacitance and output capacitance different in a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, capacitance

I was reading this [data sheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFZ44N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d) on a MOSFET. In this datasheet it says the "input capacitance" is 1470 pF, and the "output capacitance" is 360 pF.

How is it possible to have a different input and output capacitance? Shouldn't it be the exact same capacitance for both the input and output because you have the exact same capacitor in both scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "*because you have the exact same capacitor in both scenarios?*"

And which two terminals are you imagining each capacitor being across?

Because the two terminals that are the input of a MOSFET are different than those that are the output.

[image]
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-effects-of-MOSFET-output-capacitance-in-high-Gauen/6bb30165d5dc900c2c4fac43143558a31064f9c7